# Connecting recursion with other function together | canvas, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, recursion

I'm trying to make an animation of a "growing tree". The problem is i cannot connect these two functions below to make it work correctly.

So far i have a function that draws a straight line (trunk) from the bottom to the top:
http://jsfiddle.net/FTCcW/1/

And here's the code of the function that draws the whole tree:

```
function stick(d) {

    if (d==0)
        return;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0,70);
    context.lineTo(0,0);
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
    context.stroke();

    if (d==1) {
        context.strokeStyle = 'green';
        context.stroke(); }


    context.save();
    context.scale(0.75,0.75);
    context.translate(-35,-60);
    context.rotate(-30 * Math.PI/180);
    stick(d-1);
    context.restore();


    context.save();
    context.scale(0.75,0.75);
    context.translate(35,-60);
    context.rotate(30 * Math.PI/180);
    stick(d-1);
    context.restore();
}

stick(17);
```

I tried a few options but none of them gave the right result so i've decided to ask for some help.

Comment: **Warning**: Your fiddle uses a `setInterval`, but never stops it! Make sure to use `clearInterval`, or better use `setTimeout` with conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with animations is that you have to split your algorithm in steps.

That means that you must transform your recursive algorithm into an iterative one.

To do that, you can:

1. Split your `stick` function in subfunctions [[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FTCcW/4/)]:

   ```
   function pre(i) {
       context.save();
       context.scale(0.75,0.75);
       context.translate(i * 35,-60);
       context.rotate(i * 30 * Math.PI/180); 
   }
   function post() {
       context.restore();
   }
   function middle(d) {
       context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo(0,70);
       context.lineTo(0,0);
       context.lineWidth = 3;
       context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
       context.stroke();

       if (d==1) {
           context.strokeStyle = 'green';
           context.stroke();
       }
   }
   function stick(d, i) {
       if(i) pre(i);
       if(d > 0) {
           middle(d);
           stick(d-1, -1);
           stick(d-1, 1);
       }
       if(i) post();
   }
   ```
2. Instead of calling the functions, push the calls to a queue (array), and loop it:

   ```
   function stick(n, i) {
       function main(d, i) {
           // Note the order of pushing is the inverse!
           // You must push first the last function

           if(i) queue.push([], post);
           if(d > 0) {
               queue.push([d-1,-1], main);
               queue.push([d-1,1], main);
               queue.push([d], middle);
           }
           if(i) queue.push([i], pre);
       }

       queue.push([n, 0], main);

       while(queue.length) {
           (queue.pop()).apply(null, queue.pop());
       }
   }
   ```

Full code [[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FTCcW/2/)]:

```
function stick(n, i) {
    var queue = [];

    function pre(i) {
        context.save();
        context.scale(0.75,0.75);
        context.translate(i * 35,-60);
        context.rotate(i * 30 * Math.PI/180); 
    }
    function post() {
        context.restore();
    }
    function middle(d) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0,70);
        context.lineTo(0,0);
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
        context.stroke();

        if (d==1) {
            context.strokeStyle = 'green';
            context.stroke();
        }
    }
    function main(d, i) {
        if(i) queue.push([], post);
        if(d > 0) {
            queue.push([d-1,-1], main);
            queue.push([d-1,1], main);
            queue.push([d], middle);
        }
        if(i) queue.push([i], pre);
    }

    queue.push([n, 0], main);

    while(queue.length) {
        (queue.pop()).apply(null, queue.pop());
    }
}
```

Now, it's trivial to convert it to an animation. Just replace the while loop with the following:

```
(function step() {
    if (queue.length) {
        (queue.pop()).apply(null, queue.pop());
        setTimeout(step, 100);
    }
})();
```

But, since only `main` function does a visual change, better use [[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FTCcW/3/)]

```
(function step() {
    if (queue.length) {
        var f = queue.pop(),
            args = queue.pop();
        f.apply(null, args);
        if(f === main) setTimeout(step, 100);
        else step();
    }
})();
```

Or you may want to do more operations at each step, [[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FTCcW/5/)]:

```
var iter = 1000;
(function step() {
    var i = iter,
        d = new Date();
    while (queue.length && --i>=0) {
        var f = queue.pop(),
            args = queue.pop();
        f.apply(null, args);
    }
    iter = Math.max(50, iter*60/(new Date()-d)|0);
    if (queue.length) f === main ? setTimeout(step, 100) : step();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's really helpful. I'll play around with the code.